# Tastypie: Is there a way to invalidate Cache after resource Update?

Tags: django, rest, caching, tastypie

I have a Django (1.8.17) app, and I am using Tastypie (0.13.3) as REST API Framework.
I have some very simple resources, and I use `SimpleCache` to cache them for 15 minutes.

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from my_app.models import MyModel
from tastypie.cache import SimpleCache


class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    cache = SimpleCache(timeout=900)
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

The problem: When I update the Resource by a `PUT` request, the resource gets updated in DataBase, but doesn't get invalidated from cache, so I continue to get the old data for 15 minutes, which is inconvenient, I would like that when the resource get updated, it will be fetched from DB and cached again. Is there someone who faced the same issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Django returning stale cache data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849236/why-is-django-returning-stale-cache-data)

Comment: @e4c5 NO, it is not.

Comment: It is the packages are different but the core problem and the solution are the same

Comment: @e4c5 No the core Problem is not the same, and the solution is not really useful. I digged inside Tastypie and Django Caching and found an efficient and straightforward solution !

Comment: Then either post it or delete the question

Comment: @e4c5 Done, I posted thy answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search without finding any thing, I got an idea ! Override the `PUT` method by just deleting the object from cache each time it gets updated, and this is the natural way that should happen from the beginning.
I found that Tastypie's SimpleCache is using Django's Core Cache (at least in this case; think settings), so here it is how I solved the problem:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from my_app.models import MyModel
from tastypie.cache import SimpleCache
from django.core.cache import cache


class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    cache = SimpleCache(timeout=900)
    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()

    def put_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Build the key
        key = "{0}:{1}:detail:pk={2}".format(kwargs['api_name'], kwargs['resource_name'], kwargs['pk'])
        cache.delete(key)
        return super(MyModelResource, self).put_detail(request, **kwargs)
```